# Having docker installed causes $hostname on host to resolved to docker subnet instead of lan

Tags: linux, docker, networking, python-asyncio

I'm seeing some strange behavior when I spool up an asyncio.server object.

The first time I try to create a server, I get the correct subnet, the following is the **str** of the server object that is returned from create_server:

`<Server sockets=[<socket.socket fd=11, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=6, laddr=('192.168.1.201', 11000)>]>`

all subsequent attempt yield the following result:

`<Server sockets=[<socket.socket fd=11, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=2049, proto=6, laddr=('172.17.0.1', 11000)>]>`

which is not the right subnet. Afterwards, no matter how time I do it, I always get the wrong 172 subnet. Interestingly, if I wait ~10 minutes or so, same shell and everything, it creates a 192 server again.

Now I can fix this by just hardcoding an ip, but I'd like it to dynamically figure out the right ip.

The following is the return of ifconfig:

```
br-342acaa4303c Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:be:b3:db:e1  
      inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:47:5a:65:5e  
      inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::42:47ff:fe5a:655e/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:32679 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:43453 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:15617732 (14.8 MiB)  TX bytes:51666811 (49.2 MiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:c4:7a:c1:1e:5b  
      inet addr:192.168.1.201  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::ec4:7aff:fec1:1e5b/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:3643491 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:674975 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:5227031297 (4.8 GiB)  TX bytes:481938346 (459.6 MiB)
      Memory:df100000-df17ffff 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:c4:7a:c1:1e:5a  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:16 Memory:df200000-df220000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:47936 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:47936 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:423659124 (404.0 MiB)  TX bytes:423659124 (404.0 MiB)

vethc2392f6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ba:8f:5e:03:b1:cf  
      inet6 addr: fe80::b88f:5eff:fe03:b1cf/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:18753 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:21294 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:15111040 (14.4 MiB)  TX bytes:18790175 (17.9 MiB)
```

The /etc/hosts on the host is:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       <hostname>

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Note, I do have a docker container running on the machine, which appears to be where the 172 is coming from, but I am trying to run the process from the host, not the docker container. I do have a feeling that docker may to blame, which is why I added it as a tag.

Comment: Regarding the question: `create_server` resolves the host by [calling](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5f3d04fa4e9b3c3b0e4807f8516de9365bfed467/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L1253) `loop.getaddrinfo` which [in turn](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5f3d04fa4e9b3c3b0e4807f8516de9365bfed467/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L765) calls [`socket.getaddrinfo`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5f3d04fa4e9b3c3b0e4807f8516de9365bfed467/Lib/socket.py#L731), a wrapper over the [POSIX C function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freeaddrinfo.html) of the same name.

Comment: When I call the socket.getaddrinfo from a python console it returns only the docker adapters. If i call it on a hostname that is on the network it returns the correct subnet (192.) So I'm guessing that docker is higher priority when doing getaddrinfo on the $hostname.. any idea how to change that?

Comment: Small update, not running any containers or even the docker service, the problem is still there. So it appears to be a configuration issue.

 Using linux's ping on my own $hostname resolves to the 172 subnet, probably because it uses getaddrinfo under the hood.

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/hosts`?